# Using printf and substitute changes visual selection

Tags: vim

I've been working on implementing a simple utility into Vim which allows me to visually select some text, calculate the result, then replace the original text with the result. I've run into a problem, however: it appears that somehow using `substitute` in conjunction with `printf` changes my visual selection. 
Here's the code:

```
vnoremap <leader>C y<ESC>:call setreg( '"', printf( '%f', eval( substitute( substitute( getreg( '"' ), '\n', '', 'g' ), '\(\d\+\.\=\d*\)\s*\^\s*\(\d\+\.\=\d*\)', 'pow( \1, \2 )', 'g' ) ) ), getregtype( '"' ) )<CR>gvp
```

Now, it's a *bit* lengthy, but I'm working on fixing that. Basically, it takes the visually selected text, yanks it, then sets the `"` register to contain the evaluated response, then re-selects the last visual selection, then pastes it, replacing the visual selection with the result.

As an example, say I have this line: `a = 32 - 2`. Visually select `32 - 2`, then hit `<leader>C`. The line ends up being `a = 30.0000002 - 2`.

The problem is in the last bit of the last substitution: when the `'\(\d\+\.\=\d*\)\s*\^\s*\(\d\+\.\=\d*\)'`
bit doesn't have the last `\.\=\d*`, the code runs fine (given the exponent/index isn't a float). Without `printf`, it works fine given there are no floats. With `printf` **and** the last bit, only the first character is replaced, but the output is correct.

I need to use `printf`, though, because that allows me to use floats. I also need to do that substitution, because it allows me to use exponents.

What's happening, and how do I fix it? It doesn't make since that the visual area would be changed just by using that code inside of printf. Am I just missing something really obvious?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you provide a simple example, that does exhibit the behaviour? Show the text clearly before and after you applied the mapping and what you expect.

Comment: Yes, `substitute()` can change the unnamed register.  Use one of the named registers instead.  Also you might consider making that a function, rather than cramming everything on a single line.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I added an example to the question.

Comment: @Sato Katsura: I tried using a named register and got the same results. I also intend on moving it to a function once I get it working.

Comment: @DavisDude, can't reproduce

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: That's weird. What OS are you using? Maybe it's OS specific? (I'm Windows 10)

Comment: @DavisDude, sorry, seems I can reproduce at least sometimes. Will check, if this is a bug and can be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the unnamed register doesn't survive mode changes.  However, according to the manual:

> Writing to the "" register writes to register "0.

And indeed, changing `gvp` to `gv"0p` makes your macro work.  However, I suggest using a slightly safer version instead:

```
function! s:expr_eval()                                            
    let old_expr = @"
    let reg_type = getregtype('"')
    let expr = substitute(old_expr, '\n', '', 'g')
    let expr = substitute(expr, '\v(\d+%(\.\d*)?)\s*\^\s*(\d+%(\.\d*)?)', 'pow(\1, \2)', 'g')
    try
        let expr = printf('%f', eval(expr))
    catch
        let expr = old_expr
    endtry
    call setreg('"', expr, reg_type)
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> <leader>C  y:<C-u>call <SID>expr_eval()<CR>gv"0p
```

Comment: Changing to `gv"0p` did not work for me, but your function did.